# Kotlin: check if list has an object of a specific type

Tags: list, class, inheritance, kotlin

I have an interface:

```
interface Change
```

and a function:

```
 fun test (listOfChanges: List<Change>)
```

and this class that implements `Change` interface:

```
 class MyChange :Change
```

How to check if `listOfChanges` has an element of `MyChange` class?

Like: `if(listOfchanges.contains(MyChange::class)`

Answer (score 25):

You can use `any()`:

```
listOfChanges.any { it is MyChange }
```

Comment: thank you. What about  `listOfChanges.filterIsInstance(MyChange::class.java).isNotEmpty()` ? Which method will work faster?

Comment: @MukhamedaliZhadigerov Both `any()` and `filterIsInstance()` will iterate over the list. However, `any()` returns immediately after the first element that matches the given predicate is found, while `filterIsInstance()` always iterates until the end of the list to store the result. Also `filterIsInstance()` creates a new list. So `any()` seems better for your case.